# I want to replace all the occurrence of a "word" with <mark>word</mark>

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace all the occurrence of a "word" with mark tags enclosing the word

This is my Input string

```
var temp='<div title="Minimum Standards for Child Protection in Humanitarian Action (CPMS) | content of" >
  Child protection
</div>';
```

My expected output is

```
var temp='<div title="Minimum Standards for Child Protection in Humanitarian Action (CPMS) | content of" >
  <mark>Child</mark> protection
</div>';
```

But the output i am getting is

```
var temp='<div title="Minimum Standards for <mark>Child</mark> Protection in Humanitarian Action (CPMS) | content of" >
  <mark>Child</mark> protection
</div>';
```

It replaces the word child inside the "title" attribute. but i want to avoid the replace inside the title attribute.How can i do this?

This is my present code

```
var searchText="child";
var re = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');
let htmlDataString = String(temp).replace(re, "<mark>$&</mark>");
```

Comment: `I want to replace all the occurrence of a “word” ` title is completely opposite to explanation.

Comment: I wrote some code that does something similar if you want to check it out. https://gist.github.com/tomshaw/def66e5b1846309d1ed3cfd6fb5153e7

Comment: @AZ_ I have edited the question. Stackoverflow didn't allow writing tags in plain text.It replaces the tags with the contents in ti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```js
var temp = '<div title="Minimum Standards for Child Protection in Humanitarian Action (CPMS) | content of" >Child protection</div><div title="Minimum Standards for Child Protection in Humanitarian Action (CPMS) | content of" >Child protection</div>';

let domparser = new DOMParser()
let doc = domparser.parseFromString(temp, "text/html")

let searchText = "child";
let re = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');

doc.body.querySelectorAll('[title]').forEach(el => {
  el.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace(re, "<mark>$&</mark>");
})

document.write(doc.body.innerHTML)
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML)
```

Comment: Hi the input string is a complete DOM page .It has many title tags in multiple elements.I think this is not possible in that case

Comment: <div title="Minimum Standards for Child Protection in Humanitarian Action (CPMS) | content of" >Child protection</div><div title="Minimum Standards for Child Protection in Humanitarian Action (CPMS) | content of" >Child protection</div>

this content aginst not working

Comment: @chandukomati use `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that might help you

```
var temp= '<div title="Minimum Standards for Child Protection in Humanitarian Action (CPMS) | content of" > Child protection </div>';
var found = $(temp).filter("div").html();
var text = $(temp).filter("div").html().replace('Child','<mark>Child</mark>');
let htmlDataString = String(temp).replace(found, text);
```

output of the above code

```
<div title="Minimum Standards for Child Protection in Humanitarian Action (CPMS) | content of" > <mark>Child</mark> protection </div>
```